# How to dissmiss the keyboard of ipad when it is on the Modal view controller and presentation style is UIModalPresentationFormSheet?

Tags: ios4

I am presenting the Modal View Controller with Style `UIModalPresentationFormSheet`. And I have to dismiss the Keyboard, but I am unable to do so.

Comment: Please tell us what you tried and how it doesn't work.

Comment: I am presenting the Modal View Controller with Style UIModalPresentationFormSheet on Ipad.On that I have the UITextField.On click of Return Button I want to dismiss the KeyBoard.I tried the following code.                                           
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextgField *)textField
{
  [textField resignFirstResponder];
  return NO;
} 
But KeyBoard is not getting dismissed.When I am using UIModalPresentationFullScreen or UIModalPresentationPageSheet style then keyboard is getting dismissed.Only for UIModalPresentationFormSheet I am facing the problem.